# JS Why Won't This Console.Log Evaluate Properly?

Tags: javascript, concatenation, console.log

```js
let a=3, b=4, c=5;
console.log(`b > a ` + b>a);
console.log(`c < a ` + c<a);
console.log(`!(a<b)` + !(a<b));
```

Why is it that the last line is executed with the proper string + the result, but the other two don't include the string?

Comment: hint : `'b > a 4' > 3` is false

Comment: Because you're concatenating the string to the boolean value. Separate the arguments properly using `,` instead of `+`. Voting to close as a typographical issue.

Comment: ORDER OF OPERATIONS. Your first console is this.`var x = \`b > a \` + b; console.log(x > a);` Now if you add parens, `console.log(\`b > a \` + (b>a));`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of operator precedence. Arithmetic operators have higher precedence than comparison operators (so you can write things like `if (x + y > z)`), so

```
console.log(`b > a ` + b>a);
```

is equivalent to

```
console.log((`b > a ` + b) > a);
```

This logs the result of the comparison between `'b > a 4'` and `3`.

You want to concatenate the result of the comparison, so you have to write

```
console.log(`b > a ` + (b > a));
```

to override the default precedence.

Your last example works as intended because `!(a<b)` groups the comparison together as a single expression, similar to `(b > a)` in my rewrite.